# Dynamic family tree

Tags: css, tree, dynamically-generated, family-tree

I want to generate a family tree using data i receive from a file. I wonder how I should start. I've seen various examples of peoples using unordered lists but the problem is that the marriage relationship is not displayed correctly. I'm referring to this tutorial: http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree . If possible I wanted to do it by myself not using any thirdparty libraries.

Do you guys have a idea about it?

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by 'unordered lists'?

Comment: With unordered lists I meant the approach from the example in which all data is structured in unordered lists.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of 'family tree' is misleading as it must NOT use a tree! but a graph. then using a tree you will have by definition a root node to the tree and as you know it takes two to give life.

Now that we understand it should be a graph, the relation of each family should be two to many, as every family (married or not) has two parents and unknown number of children.

The question you need to ask yourself is how the data will be modeled and how do you want to display it.